# Send e-mail in a workflow : Conditional display field on email in share point designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, send-email

I want to conditionally display a field in the email body, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow variable. Set the workflow variable value as email body text if the condition matches.
Use the variable to in the body part of send email activity.